# Chrome extension development: Get number of tabs in window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I the number of tabs in a a window? I want to use this value in an if clause then:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) { 
    if (numberOfTabs >= X) {
    // do something
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.tabs.query()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) "gets all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified."

For tabs in the current window: `chrome.tabs.query({'currentWindow' : true}), ...`.

It returns an array of `Tab`s (so `tabs.length` should give you the number of open tabs).